# Why interface can not have variable but abstract class can

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I came across this question in interview; We can not instantiate abstract class and interface then why can not we declare variable in interface though we can declare it in abstract class?

Comment: An interface is a contract without implementation details like fields. An abstract class can be used interface-like, but can contain implementation details for derived classes (reusability).

Comment: _Fields_ are supposed to be internal to a class object. Where they need to be exposed, they should be done through _properties_. An interface allows you to define properties.